# S3 as a drive using rclone

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, rclone

I want to setup s3 as a network drive for my ec2 instance using rclone in my windows ec2 instance but it is not working for every user in my windows server I tried with any other user but the service is not running and also with only one user the drive is showing in file explorer.

I am trying to map s3 as a drive using rclone in my windows ec2 instance but it is not working for every user in my windows server I tried with any other user but the service is not running and also with only one user the drive is showing in file explorer but after closing of command prompt the drive is not showing in the file explorer how can I automate it and drive is working for all users (how can I make aws access keys and password is available for all user).

Comment: Have you mounted it via the SYSTEM account as mentioned in the [Windows Caveats section](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/#windows-caveats)?